# xpath for named LabeledStatement or BreakStatement

Tags: pmd

I want to create a PMD rule to forbid usage of labeled statements

Sadly I could not find a common XPath for such statements.

I need a XPath query which finds

//LabeledStatement for the labels itself

and for the 
ContinueStatement and BreakStatement i would need a possiblity to check if a label is defined there.
From the PMD Rule builder (XPath builder) the labels are defined as:

BreakStatement:loop (loop is the defined label name and could be anything)

ContinueStatement:loop (loop is the defined label name and could be anything)

can someone give me a hint what XPath I should define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on a very good track. Using the rule designer is a great way to figure this one out, specially since PMD 6.0.0 which revamped the GUI.

As you figured, `//LabeledStatement` will match all labels (which you don't want), and `//BreakStatement` and `//ContinueStatement` will flag all break / continues, which you only want to flag if they are followed by a tag.

Therefore, you simply need to check if those have a tag set or not. Using the designer to inspect properties of those AST nodes makes it easy to figure it out, the attribute where the label is stored is the `Image`, which is null when none is defined. As XPath stringifies all attributes, a null value is an empty string.

[image: PMD Rule Designer]

Therefore:

```
//LabeledStatement | //BreakStatement[@Image != ""] | //ContinueStatement[@Image != ""]
```

Will match:

1. All labels
2. All breaks with a label
3. All continues with a label